Is there any way to get both compact type in React-Grid-Layout Library
I am building a website in which I am using vertical Compact but for example in a row there are two grid items that are identical, Now If the user dragged the item 1 over 2, then I want to swap their position instead of getting one above another.
I have tried many ways to get this from onDragStart and onDragEnd Event listers, also I have tried changing the core Utility file of the library, but still not successful. I have got few references from this article on the Github issue

Please show the code of what you tried.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
